# How to iterate over checkbox in angular so it becomes dynamic?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I have harcoded checkbox which is like this:

[image]

The code looks like:

```
<h5>Document List</h5>
<div class="form-check">
   <label class="form-check-label" for="check1">
   <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check1" name="proformaInvoice" value="something" [(ngModel)]="processAnexOne.proformaInvoice" value="checked" >Proforma Invoice
   </label>
</div>
```

The Json data coming is :

[image]

The method to call the api to get json data is:

```
ngOnInit() {
         this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/documents')
      .subscribe((data: any[]) => {
        this.documents = data;
        console.log(this.documents);
      })
  }
```

How can i bin these json data into the checkbox so that it becomes dynamic?

Comment: Could you elaborate your question.

Comment: i have a static checkbox . i need to show the json data into the chekcbox dynamically like if there is 10 json data then there should be 10checkboxes automatically.

Comment: I think he wants to create checkboxes based on the result from the json.

Comment: check this https://coryrylan.com/blog/creating-a-dynamic-checkbox-list-in-angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `*ngFor` to iterate over the `documents`. Note : You can add one property in `document` where you can `bind` the `value` of `checkbox`. Here I added the property `selected`.

```
<div class="form-check" *ngFor="let document of documents">
   <label class="form-check-label" for="check1">
   <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" 
        id="check1" name="proformaInvoice"
        [value]= "document.docName"
        [(ngModel)]="document.selected"
        >Proforma Invoice
   </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML, check with ngIf if the data has already arrived. If not, do not display the div.

In the inner div run an ngFor on your documents.

```
<h5>Document List</h5>
<div class="form-check" *ngIf="dataIsPresent">
  <div *ngFor="let document of documents">
   <label class="form-check-label" for="check1">
   <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="document.docName" value="something"  value="document.docName" >{{document.docName}}
   </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

In your TS create a boolean to check if data has arrived or not.

```
dataIsPresent: Boolean = false;
ngOnInit() {
         this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/documents')
      .subscribe((data: any[]) => {
        this.documents = data;
        this.dataIsPresent = true;
        console.log(this.documents);
      })
  }
```

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *ngFor directive to iterate documents and create check boxes

```
<div *ngFor="let obj of documents">
    <div class="form-check">
       <label class="form-check-label" for="check1">
           <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check1"
           name="proformaInvoice" value="something" 
           [(ngModel)]="obj.value" value="checked" >Proforma 
           Invoice
       </label>
    </div>
</div>
```